# Hypernym for "bark", "meow", "roar"

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

Is there a hypernym for animal noises like "bark", "meow", "roar", et cetera?

Comment: Cry: the utterance or call of an animal.

Comment: "Call", as in "bird call" or "cat call", refers to the sound each animal makes.

Comment: @tylerharms: Please don't use [cat call](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/catcall?q=cat+call) in that sense ever.

Comment: @TusharRaj: I'm not sure what sense you're implying. The word in question is "call".

Comment: @tylerharms "Cat call" has a specific and primary negative meaning and you are likely to be misunderstood if you use it to refer to the sound made by a cat.  Saying that it's "call" as in "cat call" is confusing.  (Also IMO a meow is not a call, neither is a bark -- though a howl might be.)

Comment: I can't speak for all cats, but the ones I know seem to be calling me (for want of food or attention mainly) with their meows. As to the use of the term “cat call", I agree that it probably doesn't call a meow to mind, but the utterance of a cat is where it comes from. While I would probably just call it a cat “sound ", as a hypernym that word is not useful.

Comment: But, what does the fox 'say'?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Wikipedia calls them [animal sounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_sounds).

Or simply `sounds`, as in:

> Lion sounds include snarling, hissing, coughing, miaowing, woofing, and roaring. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion#Communication))

The wikipedia article states that "a majority of them are onomatopoeia" (= not *all* of them are).

Josh's suggestion [cry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cry) has merit

> 2. The loud characteristic call of a bird or other animal
>
> *Imagining their hoots to be the cry of some dangerous animal, she had spent nearly two terrified days on the run from her rescuers.*

The example clearly uses the word as a hypernym.

Answer (score 14):

The technical term I have heard is *vocalize* - making a noise with their mouth. This applies to an owl's hooting, a cow's moo, and so on. This wouldn't cover crickets, I suppose, but then nor does "cry".

Answer (score 13):

Animal noises are onomatopoeic.

> **onomatopoeia**
>
> 1. the formation of a word such as "cuckoo", "meow", "honk" or "boom" by imitation of a sound made by or associated with its referent
> 2. A word so formed

*Source: Dictionary.com*

Comment: I don't think *onomatopoeia* is the hypernym OP is looking for.

Comment: It's too broad. A steel worker is a human, but if you say "human", nobody will first and foremost think of a steel worker.

Comment: @Josh61 What do you mean? At the time I answered this question it was actually "term" rather than "hypernym". RegDwight edited it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question from the start.

Comment: Maybe I did - I have a tendency to do such things. What is your interpretation?

Comment: The revisions are [public](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/248812/revisions). It did not say "term". It said "general word", and was tagged "common-word".

Comment: @DogLover - no big problem ..just reconsider your answer if you like :))

Comment: @RegDwigнt That's right. I'm too used to seeing "term" I suppose. Sorry.

Comment: Anyway. It is quite obvious what the OP is looking for, and I wouldn't say you have misunderstood him, you did supply a "general word", or "common word", or a hypernym, or an "umbrella term". The only thing is that it's *too* general. It's a bit like saying that the common word for "bark, meow, roar" is *noise*, or *verb*, or *word*. It's perfectly correct. It's just not specific enough.

Comment: Thanks for those who have answered. I am not looking for a very esoteric or scientific word. I am looking for a "hypernym" to be used as a variable name in a simple computer game

Comment: @zencv then you have to consider context.  If you have a table with a column headed "animal" the next column could be headed "sound" or "cry" (or similarly some sort of character stats display).  In that case a very broad hypernym becomes less broad due to context,  If "bark" is the first suggestion of sound/animals rather than the outside of a tree, you need to be more specific.

Comment: @ChrisH well, I came across this topic when I was creating a sample to demonstrate polymorphism
Currently the code is like this:
    

public class Animal {
       protected void cry() {
        System.out.println("cry");
    }
   }
    public class Cat extends Animal {
    
    public void cry() {
      System.out.println("meaow");
    }
}

Comment: @zencv in that case you want something short and to the point.  "Cry" fits perfectly, and the class name gives the context I was imagining, just in code rather than user space.

Answer (score 2):

Another good word might be animal "calls", but those are often what animals use to communicate with each other, such as bird calls. It may not include all animal vocalizations you intend it to cover.

Answer (score 2):

Some professionals refer to the sounds an animal makes as "vocalizations", perhaps to avoid the anthropomorphic terms pet owners and animal lovers tend to use.  However, it's a bit stiff and fussy for most uses.

For scholarly examples, see 
http://www.unc.edu/~rhwiley/wildspectra/info/sounds.html
http://epublications.marquette.edu/dissertations/AAI3172488/