# How are words that describe a certain sound called?

Tags: sounds, category

They're different in different languages, but I'm looking for the name of the category of those words.

For example, a sound of dog's barking: "woof-woof". But in Russian it's "ghav-ghav";

A sound of cat: "meow". But in Japanese it's "nya".

Also various sounds that are used in comics: "boing", "bang", "poof", "ka-pow", etc.

EDIT:

These words are called "Onomatopeic"

Comment: onomatopeic :http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Onomatopeic

Comment: Oops, wrong link, your question has been answered here: [**Hypernym for “bark”, “meow”, “roar”**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248812/hypernym-for-bark-meow-roar)

Comment: Onomatopeic was the word I was looking for, thanks

Comment: Duplicate of the poorly titled [Word for words that sound like the sound](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181106/word-for-words-that-sound-like-the-sound) (though that itself was closed).

Comment: On a side note: native and fluent english speakers don't ask 'how' something is called, they ask 'what' something is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A word which demonstrates a sound is called **onomatopoeia**. Onomatopoeia is using words to represent sounds or using words that sound like what they mean, such as boom, beep, click, meow, etc.

When you pronounce an onomatopoetic word, it mimics the sound of what it is describing.